# Usage of Derived class with the std::shared_ptr of Base class

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, c++14

Is the following approach good?

```
class TA      {  };
class TB : TA {  };

std::shared_ptr<TA> spta;
spta.reset(new TB);
```

Comment: If you are using [tag:C++14], you should prefer `std::make_shared`. Among other things, it includes the we know where you live optimization. Other than that, as long as you are following Liskov's substitution principle, the base class is public, there is absolutely nothing wrong with having a pointer to the base class instead of concrete implementation.

Comment: No good. `TA` is a private base.

Comment: Is virtual destructor required for empty classes?

Comment: @LogicStuff Not for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @jnbrq -Canberk Sönmez Keep the code in your question as it was originally posted, please, so the answers make sense.

Comment: @DavidPacker why only with C++14 and not C++11?

Comment: @TheBadger AFAIK C++11 did not have `std::make_shared` yet and you had to create shared pointers with the standard `std::shared_ptr`. With C++14 you can simply do `auto shared = std::make_shared<int>(4);`. No `new` call, the type is present only once and looks nicer alltogether.

Comment: @DavidPacker According to what I can see, and my experience `std::make_shared` is in C++11. I am using it with gcc, mingw and msvc2013 with only C++11 support enabled. Also looking at [cppr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) it is listed without specifying it is only in 14, [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/) marks it as a 11 feature. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TheBadger You are right. `std::make_unique` is new in C++14, but `std::make_shared` was already present in the 11 version. Although, the WKWYL optimization came with C++14, not before. Anyway, the `std::make_*` is the prefered way to create smart pointers.

Answer (score 5):

There's one problem with the code shown, `TB` must inherit publicly from `TA`. You have a `shared_ptr<TA>`, so the pointer you want to store in it must be convertible to `TA`, but with `private` inheritance, the base is inaccessible so your code will not compile.

```
class TA             {  };
class TB : public TA {  };
```

Beyond this, the code has no errors and is well-behaved. Typically, when you perform polymorphic deletion of a derived class instance through a base class pointer, you need the base class' destructor to be `virtual` so the derived class destructor is called, but in case of `shared_ptr` this is not necessary. [`shared_ptr::reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) is a function template that'll accept any `Y*` that is convertible to the managed pointer type. The same is true for `shared_ptr`'s [constructor template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

That being said, you should prefer making the base class' destructor `virtual`, especially if the classes involved have other `virtual` functions.

Comment: The code in the question is not right, it misses at least a `public` keyword somewhere.

Comment: Yes, you're right, missed that part. But the virtual destructor is not needed, although it would be a good idea, especially if the classes involved have other virtual functions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not for `TA` is private.

Moreover, as suggested in the comments, the destructor of the base class ought to be *virtual*. It is usually a good practice, for you cannot guarantee that instances of your classes will be used only with shared pointers.

To have it working, you must at least modify these lines:

```
class TA {  };
class TB : TA {  };
```

As it follows:

```
class TA { virtual ~TA() { } };
class TB : public TA {  };
```

Those ones are *good* as the following example is *good*:

```
class TA { virtual ~TA() { } };
class TB : public TA {  };

TA *spta = nullptr;
spta = new TB;
```

It mainly depends on what *good* means for you. It's legal, at least.

Comment: @RichardHodges Not needed for `shared_ptr`, but a good idea anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't understand your comment. It is a `shared_ptr<TA>`, not a `shared_ptr<TB>`, so when the shared pointer releases the underlying object it will call `TA::~TA`, not `TB::~TB`.  In this particular case what makes it not matter is that both `TA` and `TB` are empty classes, but I don't see how `shared_ptr` makes it not matter.  I assume the classes are empty for the sake of a simplified example, but it will matter as soon as `TB` has stuff that must be destroyed.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for pointing that out. `shared_ptr` is one beautifully designed class. I was surprised to see that clang (correctly) does not emit a warning even if TA has virtual functions and no virtual destructor when used with a `shared_ptr`

Comment: @legalize Try it out with a non-empty class.

Comment: @legalize added an 'answer' to demonstrate

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question, it is an attempt to clear up any confusion about shared_ptr's seemingly magical ability to avoid the use of a virtual destructor.

Here's a little demo program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    ~A() { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }

    void foo() { do_foo(); }

protected:
    virtual void do_foo() {
        std::cout << "A::" << __func__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : A {
    ~B() { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }

    virtual void do_foo() override {
        std::cout << "B::" << __func__ << " ";
        A::do_foo();
    }
};

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> p = std::make_shared<A>();
    p->foo();
    p = std::make_unique<B>();
    p->foo();

    cout << "deleting B:" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
A::do_foo
~A
B::do_foo A::do_foo
deleting B:
~B
~A
```

Notice that the correct destructor was called when the B was destroyed at the end of main().

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `make_unique` here.  However, it appears that this works because `shared_ptr` stores the associated deleter for the template argument.  [~shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr)

Comment: I used make_unique to demonstrate that the deleter is moved from it